# Like query not working if it is integer or bigint in java postgres

Tags: java, postgresql

`Like` query not working if it is `integer` or `bigint` in **java** **postgres**.

My code is :

```
String tabname = rq.getParameter("tabname");  //table name
String fieldname = rq.getParameter("fieldname");  //field name
String fieldtext = rq.getParameter("fieldtext");  //field value

query = "select * from dbname."+ tabname +" where "+ fieldname +" like ('%"+ fieldtext +"%')" ;
```

If the **fieldtext** is `integer` or `bigint`, for example

`uid(integer), mobile(bigint) etc` the above query will not give any result.

If the **fieldtext** is `text`, for example `user name, address etc` the query get works.

Why the query not working for `integer` or `bigint` type.

Comment: 1) You're horribly open to SQL Injection.  If you can avoid it, don't dynamically specify table/field names.  Otherwise, you **NEED** to validate them against existing tables/fields before running the actual query.  2) You're attempting to compare numbers as text, which isn't going to work well - you should just be doing a regular equals

Comment: `query = "select * from dbname."+ tabname +" where "+ fieldname +"::text like ('%"+ fieldtext +"%')" ;` And use prepared statements/quote table_name, fieldname instead of concatenating string.

Comment: @lad2025, thanks it seems working...

Comment: `LIKE` is for character values, not for numbers

Comment: I'd discourage using "*" here, too.